# maped types: set key as an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am still trying to get my head around maped types, so what I am trying to achieve is a config of items that looks like this:

```
let config = {
    connA: {
      host: 'abc123',
      user: 'abc123',
      password: 'abc123',
      database: 'abc123',
    },
    connB: {
      host: 'abc123',
      user: 'abc123',
      password: 'abc123',
      database: 'abc123',
    }
}
```

I would like to setup a type for the keys `connA`, `connB`, and so on, where those could be anything.

```
export interface DatabaseConnection {
  host: string
  user: string
  password: string
  database: string
}

export type DatabaseConnections<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
```

So, when I use it, it would be something like this:

```
public static connect(config: DatabaseConnections<DatabaseConnection>) {
for (let db in config) {
  db.host
}
```

When I do this, it says that `db` is a `string`, and it should be an `object` (`connA` or `connB` in this example)

Comment: `in` iterates over the object keys. They are strings for shure

Comment: `of` can only be used on arrays and strings natively. To be used on objects you need to define an iterator (as it tells you). You may use `Object.values` or a `Map` instead of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are not looking for mapped types. You are looking for an index signature

```
export type DatabaseConnections<T> = {
  [name: string]: T
}

public static connect(config: DatabaseConnections<DatabaseConnection>) {
   for (let db in config) {
      config[db] // this will be of type T
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay cool! That seems like it works. I thought I did mapped types for this last time I did something similar. This will be a good thing to know!